# Access violation in nvoglv64.dll during glDrawElements

Tags: c++, opengl, nvidia, access-violation

I have some source code which builds a vertex array object (VAO) like follows:

```
GLuint vao{ 0 };
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.m_vertex_data_vbo_id);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.m_indices_vbo_id);

// multiple calls to glVertexAttribPointer for positions, normals, etc.
glVertexAttribPointer(0, static_cast<GLint>(mesh.m_position_size / sizeof(GLfloat)), GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, static_cast<GLsizei>(mesh.m_size_one_vertex), reinterpret_cast<GLvoid*>(mesh.m_position_offset));
...

glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

And later, when rendering the mesh, the following code used to be called:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawElements(mode, mesh.indices_length(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
```

This code used to work for several years and for various different 3D models. Now, all of a sudden, I get the following error:

> Exception thrown at 0x0000000053C91A02 (nvoglv64.dll) in application.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

And it can be fixed by calling the following code instead of the 2-liner above:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao);
// glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.m_vertex_data_vbo_id); // not required for the fix
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.m_indices_vbo_id); // Adding this line gets rid of the exception
glDrawElements(mode, mesh.indices_length(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
```

Why? The `glBindBuffer` calls shouldn't be neccessary in my understanding.

Comment: Why does the fix use a different VAO than the problematic code?

Comment: Ups, that was just a mistake. It is corrected now, thanks. The VAOs are exactly the same in the first and second case! The only thing which I've changed to get rid of the exception are the two additional lines with the `// Why?` comments.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, I am sure. `glBindVertexArray(0);`, `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);`, and `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);` are called exactly in that order; exactly as stated in the code above.

Comment: @j00hi Do you have to bind both `mesh.m_vertex_data_vbo_id` and `mesh.m_indices_vbo_id` or is it sufficent to bind `mesh.m_indices_vbo_id`?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Ha, good catch! It is sufficient to bind `mesh.m_indices_vbo_id`. I'll update my question accordingly to prevent setting others on the wrong track. Another finding which might be interesting: The exception also occurs if i call `glDrawElements` with a count of 1: `glDrawElements(mode, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);`

Comment: @j00hi So it seems that there is no reference to a `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` object stored in the vertex array object (or it is not valid e.g. 0). Are you sure that `mesh.m_indices_vbo_id` is valid (already created) when you create the vertex array object?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Just checked: The id is the same in both cases, when constructing the VAO and when calling `glDrawElements` (In my tests, it was 14, i.e. valid)

Comment: @j00hi Do you call `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);` anywhere else, at a point where `vao` is bound, maybe later in the code, after drawing?